# Multiple combinations of Python and SQL Server on AppVeyor

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, appveyor

How do I setup a AppVeyor build that runs multiple jobs with different combinations of SQL Server, MySQL and Python versions?

Let's say I want to run the following combinations:

- SQL Server 2012 and Python 2.7
- SQL Server 2012 and Python 3.4

---

- SQL Server 2014 and Python 2.7
- SQL Server 2014 and Python 3.4

---

- SQL Server 2016 and Python 2.7
- SQL Server 2016 and Python 3.6

---

- MySQL 5.7 and Python 2.7
- MySQL 5.7 and Python 3.6

How would I write my appveyor.yml file? This is what I have so far:

```
environment:

  matrix:

    # For Python versions available on Appveyor, see
    # http://www.appveyor.com/docs/installed-software#python

    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python27-x64"

    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python34-x64"
      DISTUTILS_USE_SDK: "1"

    - PYTHON: "C:\\Python36-x64"

services:
  - mysql
  - mssql2012sp1
  - mssql2014
  - mssql2016

platform:
  - x86

install:
  - "%PYTHON%\\python.exe -m pip install django==1.10"

test_script:
  - "%PYTHON%\\python.exe manage.py test"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are not supported dimensions for build matrix. Therefore you need to introduce environment variable for SQL server version and start it accordingly.
This YAML should work:

```
init:
- cmd: net start %SQL%
environment:
  matrix:
  - SQL: MSSQL$SQL2012SP1
    PYTHON: C:\\Python27-x64
  - SQL: MSSQL$SQL2012SP1
    PYTHON: C:\\Python34-x64
    DISTUTILS_USE_SDK: 1
  - SQL: MSSQL$SQL2014
    PYTHON: C:\\Python27-x64
  - SQL: MSSQL$SQL2014
    PYTHON: C:\\Python34-x64
    DISTUTILS_USE_SDK: 1
  - SQL: MSSQL$SQL2016
    PYTHON: C:\\Python27-x64
  - SQL: MSSQL$SQL2016
    PYTHON: C:\\Python36-x64
  - SQL: MySQL57
    PYTHON: C:\\Python27-x64
  - SQL: MySQL57
    PYTHON: C:\\Python36-x64
```

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Where can I find a list of all SQL servers and versions available on AppVeyor?

Comment: Please check [here](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/installed-software/#services-and-databases), though this part of documentation will be changed soon. Also you can explore build worker VM with [RDP](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/)

Comment: [new link](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#services) related to installed services.